# @ElementCollection for mapping List of Object class

Tags: java, hibernate

Hy,,

I use @ElementCollection for mapping List of Object class but i got an issue with message :

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean     with name 'ObjWellSvc': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.prosia.wmls.service.repo.ObjWellRepo com.prosia.wmls.service.impl.ObjWellSvcImpl.objWellRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ObjWellRepo': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.prosia.wmls.service.repo.impl.BaseImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in URL [file:/D:/NetBeansProjects/WITSML%20(Energistic)/WitsServer/src/java/cfg/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: collection element mapping has wrong number of columns: com.prosia.witsml.dataobject.CsCustomData.any type: object
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1064)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:872)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at com.prosia.wmls.service.TesterClass.<clinit>(TesterClass.java:19)
```

this is declaration of the field :

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="any", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="customdataID"))
@Column(name="any_")
protected List<Object> any;
```

so anyone can help me... for fix this issue...

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You try persist arbitrary instances of java.lang.Object. According JPA 2.0 following types are supported:

> The persistent fields or properties of an entity may be of the
>   following types: Java primitive types; java.lang.String; other Java
>   serializable types (including wrappers of the primitive types,
>   java.math.BigInteger,java.math.BigDecimal,java.util.Date,
>   java.util.Calendar[5], java.sql.Date, java.sql.Time,
>   java.sql.Timestamp, byte[], Byte[], char[], Character[], and
>   user-defined types that implement the Serializable interface); enums;
>   entity types; collections of entity types; embeddable classes (see
>   Section2.5); collections of basic and embeddable types (see Section
>   2.6).